# Log in user to AAD without App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

can I login a user to AAD without using an App Registration?

My problem is the following:
I am currently writing a python module that wraps the Power BI REST API.
Everything works fine if I register an app in AAD and authenticate via Client ID and Client Secret.

I would like to enable a user login, so that a user logs in with their credentials and can run the script with the privileges assigned to their account.
MSAL seems to support that with a PublicClientApplication and the acquire_token_interactive method. It still expects a Client ID, though.

My issue is that I would like to distribute my python module to other developers, without them having to register an app in AAD first.
After all, I can use the MicrosoftPowerBiMgmt PowerShell module without first registering an app.

How can I do that? Is there an authentication flow that does not need an App Registration?

Comment: Multi-tenant app registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant. This way you use a single client id but it works with all Azure AD tenants.

Comment: Thank you, that would work. But is that how you would develop a module intended to be shared with other developers?

Comment: Well, AZ CLI and Azure PowerShell work with a multi-tenant registration. But the Azure SDKs themselves usually require you to configure authentication (though they can utilize AZ CLI / Azure PowerShell as an authentication method without registering a client id).

Comment: Oh! Then that **is** the solution!

Comment: Hello @juunas,  I am in a similar situation. How would I make my C# or Python client app emulate the behaviour of `az login` or `Connect-AzAccount` without the end users actually having to do `az login` and `Connect-AzAccount`  ?  Want to avoid App registration.  Tried `sts.windows.net` but could not progress very far.  Thanks

Comment: Hello Ben,
Please, if you can share your findings. That would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to authenticate user without App registration with OAUTH and OPENID connect, multi-tenant authentication means a template which will be deployed on multiple tenants with same client-id and secret